# Is it ok to use a QR code as an avatar?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, self-promotion

I just noticed someone doing that on Youtube, and realized that this would be a great way to drive traffic to a personal / company / github page. Anywhere that your gravatar is shown, you are showing a link to whatever. It would also be a great way to goatse people, and would be a little difficult to detect automatically.

Comment: I think you may be overestimating the value... It'd require two devices to even follow the link. People are curious... but also lazy... It'd be interesting to see how many people did try to scan it, though.

Comment: I scanned the one on Youtube just to see what the URL was. Or even if it was a url - it could just be the finger hole game. This was on Youtube, after all.

Comment: @Catija why two devices? QR app on a mobile device will open the link. I don't remember it was different in the past. That said, it does requires extra effort, much more complex than just, well, following a simple link, so agree it has no real value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, of course. There's absolutely no problem in advertising your site on your profile page - there're even special text fields in the profile editor for this. Considering that you won't even be able to scan the code properly from anywhere outside your profile page (it has pretty low resolution and sizes) :P

Also, is this really a great way to drive traffic? How is it faster / easier to scan the QR than to see the website link on your profile page or [the expanded user card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)?

Comment: I totally forgot about the website link on the profile page - I don't use that feature myself :/

Comment: Low resolution: that sounds like a challenge. How small can we render a t.co link?

Comment: @Dan The quality loss due to resizing could spoil the fun also.